# ordering of a group

Tags: group-theory

An ordering of a group $G$ is a linear ordering $<$ on (the underlying set of) $G$
that satisfies, in addition,
$a < b \implies ac < bc ∧ ca < cb$,
for all $a,b, c \in G$.

Show that a group $G$ can be ordered if each finitely generated subgroup of $G$
can be ordered.

Comment: It is more useful to discuss what you've tried so far than to just state your problem. What are your thoughts?

Comment: btw that seems to be an interesting question. Where is it from?!

Comment: This *obviously* looks like needing a Zorn lemma proof, i.e. there exists a maximal monoid $P\subset G$ with $1\notin P$ (the "positive" elements). Then for any $g\notin P$ there is a *finite* product of $g$s and elements of $P$ that equals $1$, and similar for $g^{-1}$. This is *obviously* where the condition about finitely generated subgroups kicks in, but I don't see how exactly.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the compactness theorem for propositional logic, then this is an easy consequence.  Imagine a language in which the propositional variables (also called atomic sentences) are the inequalities $a<b$ for all elements $a,b$ of your group $G$.  You can write the requirements for an ordering of $G$ as a set $S$ of formulas built from these inequalities by means of propositional connectives.  That is, you arrange $S$ so that a truth assignment $v$ satisfies $S$ if and only if the binary relation $\{(a,b): v\text{ gives value true to }a<b\}$ is an ordering of $G$.  Then check that orderings of finitely generated subgroups of $G$ give you satisfying truth assignments for arbitrary finite subsets of $S$, so the compactness theorem gives you the result.

If you don't know the compactness theorem, there are different-looking but basically equivalent approaches, one using Tychonoff's theorem, another using ultrafilters, another (for the case of countable $G$) using König's infinity lemma.  Of course, there are also proofs that start from scratch and essentially re-prove the relevant special case of one of the tools I've mentioned here.